# F ratios, ANOVA, and 2 stage nested (mixed) models in R

Tags: r, anova, mixed-model, nested-data, f-statistic

I have data relating to strength of fabric. Each fabric comes from one of 4 batches (B), and batches come from one of 3 suppliers (A).

My question relates to the calculation and interpretation of F ratios using R depending upon whether you are classifying A and B as either both being *fixed*, or A as *fixed* and B as *random*.

I understand that standard R ANOVA output can be used for interpretation purposes assuming both A and B are *fixed*, but not if A is *fixed* and B is *random*.

Is the reason for this that the critical values used in the F test are different in the case of a *fixed* and *random* model (because the degrees of freedom are different)? Are the F values the same regardless of whether we assume that both A and B are *fixed* or A *fixed* and B *random* ie is it just the case that you need to ignore the last column of P values in the R output and instead calculate your own F values to compare against?

In this example, I think that it makes most sense if both are assumed to be *fixed* but want to also be able to discuss what difference it would have to the overall conclusions (and the calculations) if B is *random*.